# Extrair dados de um campo BLOB no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query, blob

Tenho um select onde tem uma coluna onde esta me retornando em `<BLOB>`

> QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=1
```

> RETORNO:

```
id  data_cad             user_data
12  2017-03-01 21:38:57    <Blob>
```

> No campo BLOB retorna o seguinte:

```
Msg=[Nome do operador João dos Passos]  IN=1 SECS=221
```

Preciso que minha query retorne:

```
12  2017-03-01 21:38:57    Nome do operador João dos Passos
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize o `CAST` para `CHAR`, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CAST(user_data AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM user WHERE user_id=1
```

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.